# How to add rows and columns to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, datagrid

how is it possible to add rows and columns to a DataGrid?

I am trying to write two functions like:

```
public void addRow(DataGrid grid);
public void addColumn(DataGrid grid);
```

Unfortunately the DataGrid itself doesn't have those functions by default.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it about WPF/Silverlight DataGrid?

Comment: No, it is about System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't done lots with DataGrid's lately, but for as far I know, a DataGrid has a datasource, and it's the datasource that should be extended within the code.

After extending the datasource (like a datatable), you should refresh the datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

[`This`](http://dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tips) link provides information about how to add rows to datagrid

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have thos functions by default? What about:

```
dataGrid.Columns.Add
```

Comment: Well, as I said that function doesn't exist by default

Comment: DataGrid.Columns is an ObservableCollection<T> and this class HAS a method Add(T) http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms132404.aspx